# Creating Object from Class name specified in string

Tags: c#, class, object, casting

I have a dropdownlist on a webpage which has list of all classnames , in C# code I need to instantiate object of selected items from dropdownlist and call method of it . All classes have similar methods .

```
 String sCalclationType = "N0059";
 var Calculator = Activator.CreateInstance("Calculator", sCalclationType ); 
 var count =  Calculator.DoCalculation();
```

I tried casting which shows "Cannot convert type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle' to 'CypressDataImport.DiabetesHelper.NQF0059" , Also I need to cast to type which needs to be same as dropdown item so not sure how to do that .

```
//var calc = (N0059)Calculator;
```

How do I handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

See here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx

Try this:

```
String sCalclationType = "N0059";
ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance("Calculator", sCalclationType ); 
var Calculator = (N0059)handle.Unwrap();
var count = Calculator.DoCalculation();
```

or

```
String sCalclationType = "N0059";
ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance("Calculator", sCalclationType );
Object p = handle.Unwrap();
Type t = p.GetType();
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("DoCalculation");
var count = method.Invoke(p, null);
```

Comment: In 1st method you are doing (N0059) cast but we dont know the type of class . Second method will work fine I think . Is it somehow possible to use 1st method by using inheriting all classes from some main class ?

Comment: Yes. Create a base class that contains what all calculators should have...which I guess in your case is DoCalculation....and I guess a way to add terms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the wrapped object returned by the Activator.CreateInstace() method.

To do that have a look at [ObjectHandle.Unwrap on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap.aspx).

Please also make sure you are using the fully qualified name of your type as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Below is an example of usage:

```
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "CypressDataImport.DiabetesHelper.NQF0059.N0059").Unwrap();
N0059 calculator= (N0059)obj;
```